# Azure Media Service BlockList Error (Invalid List of Blocks)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have tried to upload video using Azure Media service referred code from below link.

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/

The Request Header looks below

```
Request:    PUT /asset-967889d1-bb0d-4853-9e61-31777d9b3f4e/Wildlife.wmv?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=39af4b60-16ac-4abe-8a2f-4fdf7a90e1f3&sig=pukmGXpkVJuD4zqFm6xoCRBgGWjphO8%2BP8BtfK0GUV4%3D&st=2017-06-15T17%3A20%3A18Z&se=2017-06-30T17%3A20%3A18Z&comp=blocklist HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: video/x-ms-wmv
x-ms-blob-content-type: video/x-ms-wmv
Referer: http://localhost:56509/Admin/Users
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: ourhost.net
Content-Length: 7164
DNT: 1
Connection:Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Sample Request Body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BlockList><Latest>YmxvY2stMDAwMDAw</Latest>
<Latest>YmxvY2stMDAwMDAwMQ==</Latest>
</BlockList>
```

Thrown an error in response body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidBlockList</Code><Message>The specified block list is invalid.
RequestId:0e320a80-0001-001f-06fb-e59187000000
Time:2017-06-15T17:21:29.5286217Z</Message></Error>
```

Please give some direction to fix this issue.

Updated : I append the another 0 in the 1st block id.

Now My request body looks below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BlockList>
<Latest>YmxvY2stMDAwMDAwMA==</L‌​atest>
<Latest>YmxvY2‌​stMDAwMDAwMQ==</Late‌​st>
<Latest>YmxvY2stM‌​DAwMDAwMg==</Latest>‌​
<Latest>YmxvY2stMDAw‌​MDAwMw==</Latest>
</B‌​lockList>
```

Throws the Same Error in Response Body.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidBlockList</Code>
<Message>The specified block list is invalid.
    RequestId:520e710f-0001-0008-4165-e651e4000000
    Time:2017-06-16T06:01:04.0358396Z</Message></Error>
```

Javascript Call :

```
                                              // Getting the File Data from the Uploaded Html Filetype="Input"
                                                    var fileData = $("#mediatypeUpload")[0].files[0];
                                                    // Getting the Sas Url with Signature
                                                    var TSasUrl = data.Path;
                                                    var iqs = TSasUrl.indexOf("?");
                                                    LocatorId = data.Id;
                                                    SasUrl = TSasUrl.substring(0, iqs) + '/' + fileData.name + TSasUrl.substring(iqs);
                                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                                    var fileContent = selectedFile.slice(currentFilePointer, currentFilePointer + maxBlockSize);
                                                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent);





                                                    //Upload the File

                                                    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                                                        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
                                                            var requestData = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
                                                            var blockId = blockIdPrefix + pad(blockIds.length, 7);
                                                            console.log("block id = " + blockId);
                                                            blockIds.push(btoa(blockId));
                                                            var uri = SasUrl + '&comp=block&blockid=' + blockIds[blockIds.length - 1];

                                                            $.ajax({
                                                                url: uri,
                                                                crossDomain: true,
                                                                type: "PUT",
                                                                data: requestData,
                                                                processData: false,
                                                                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                                                                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
                                                                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestData.length);                                                                           
                                                                },
                                                                success: function (data, status) {
                                                                    console.log(data);
                                                                    console.log(status);
                                                                    bytesUploaded += requestData.length;
                                                                    var percentComplete = ((parseFloat(bytesUploaded) / parseFloat(selectedFile.size)) * 100).toFixed(2);
                                                                    $("#fileUploadProgress").text(percentComplete + " %");

                                                                    uploadFileInBlocks();


                                                                },
                                                                error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                                                                    console.log('Final ---- ' + desc);
                                                                    console.log('Final ------ ' + err);
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                    };

                                                    function uploadFileInBlocks() {
                                                        if (totalBytesRemaining > 0) {
                                                            console.log("current file pointer = " + currentFilePointer + " bytes read = " + maxBlockSize);
                                                            var fileContent = selectedFile.slice(currentFilePointer, currentFilePointer + maxBlockSize);
                                                            var blockId = blockIdPrefix + pad(blockIds.length, 7);
                                                            console.log("block id = " + blockId);
                                                            blockIds.push(btoa(blockId));
                                                            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent);
                                                            currentFilePointer += maxBlockSize;
                                                            totalBytesRemaining -= maxBlockSize;
                                                            if (totalBytesRemaining < maxBlockSize) {
                                                                maxBlockSize = totalBytesRemaining;
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            commitBlockList();
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    function commitBlockList() {
                                                        var uri = SasUrl + '&comp=blocklist';
                                                        console.log(uri);
                                                        var requestBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList>';
                                                        for (var i = 0; i < blockIds.length; i++) {
                                                            requestBody += '<Latest>' + blockIds[i] + '</Latest>';
                                                        }
                                                        requestBody += '</BlockList>';
                                                        console.log(requestBody);
                                                        alert('Req ' + requestBody);
                                                        $.ajax({
                                                            url: uri,
                                                            type: "PUT",
                                                            data: requestBody,
                                                            contentType: 'application/xml',
                                                            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                                                                alert('2' +requestBody);
                                                                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-content-type', selectedFile.type);
                                                                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestBody.length);
                                                            },
                                                            success: function (data, status) {
                                                                console.log(data);
                                                                console.log(status);
                                                            },
                                                            error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                                                                console.log(desc);
                                                                console.log(err);
                                                            }
                                                        });

                                                    }

                                                    function pad(number, length) {
                                                        var str = '' + number;
                                                        while (str.length < length) {
                                                            str = '0' + str;
                                                        }
                                                        return str;
                                                    }
```

Html Code :

```
                       <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label>Media Type</label>
                                <select placeholder="" class="form-control" id="mediatypeSelect">
                                    <option value="">- Select -</option>
                                    <option value="document">Document</option>
                                    <option value="image">Image</option>
                                    <option value="audio">Audio</option>
                                    <option value="video">Video</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label>Upload File</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="mediatypeUpload" >
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                                        <span id="fileUploadProgress" class="sr-only">0% Complete</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div id="fileName"></div>
                                <div id="fileSize"></div>
                                <div id="fileType"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-right">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddResource">Add</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="cancelResource">Cancel</button>



                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is because the `block ids` are not of same length. Based on the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) (see URI Parameters section), the block ids must be of same length.

If I do this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("YmxvY2stMDAwMDAw"));
```

I get an output of `block-000000`

While if I do the same with your 2nd block id:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("YmxvY2stMDAwMDAwMQ=="));
```

I get an output of `block-0000001`.

As you can see that the block id length of 2 are different (1st one is 12 characters and the 2nd one 13 characters). Please change the 1st block id to `block-0000000` (essentially append another `0`) and then this error should go away.

Comment: @ Gavrav Mantri :                                                                            Thanks Gaurav Mantri. The time you spend to analyze our issue. I append the another 0 in the 1st block id .                                           Now my Request Header like :                                                              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList><Latest>YmxvY2stMDAwMDAwMA==</Latest><Latest>YmxvY2stMDAwMDAwMQ==</Latest><Latest>YmxvY2stMDAwMDAwMg==</Latest><Latest>YmxvY2stMDAwMDAwMw==</Latest></BlockList> . Still It's show the same error.

Comment: Please don't put these in comments (it's hard to read + things get lost in comments). Please update your question and add this information there.

Comment: Thank you for sharing details about the code. I think there's an issue with how the block id is converted to a base64 string. For example, when I try to convert `YmxvY2‌​stMDAwMDAwMQ==` back to regular string I get an error message stating that the string is not a valid base64 encoded string. That could be the reason for the error you're getting. Can you please tell us the browser (with version) and OS on which you're running this code?

Comment: I am using the IE 11 (11.0.900.18282) and Windows 7.